# Jsoup giving error while parsing Html

Tags: android, html, parsing

The code works fine in java console but when in android emulator it gives an error. I have checked other post of the same type but got no success...

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidGPSTrackingActivity extends Activity {
//some code which calls directions

    }



    public void directions() {
        try {

                        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://10.0.2.2/kj/jhjh.htm")
                    .get();////////////////error occurs here
            Elements el = doc.getElementsByClass("lkklk");
            String str = el.text();
            str = str.replaceAll("[0-9]+[.] ", "\n");
            string = str.split("\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

following is the error......

```
01-19 05:34:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(952): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-19 
05:34:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(952): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup
01-19 
05:34:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(952):    at com.example.gpstracking.AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.directions(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java:308)
01-19 
05:34:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(952):    at com.example.gpstracking.AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.onActivityResult(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java:193)
01-19 
05:34:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(952):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5192)

01-19 05:34:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(952):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3137)
01-19 
05:34:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(952):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3184)
01-19 
05:34:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(952):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:130)
01-19 
05:34:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(952):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243)
01-19 
05:34:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(952):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-19 
05:34:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(952):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

01-19 05:34:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(952):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-19 
05:34:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(952):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-19 
05:34:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(952):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-19 
05:34:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(952):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-19 
05:34:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(952):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-19 
05:34:35.723: E/AndroidRuntime(952):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Did you copy the jsoup jar into the `libs` folder?

Comment: yes I have added the jar in library.  I have a similar code running in my Java where i have included it in the library. And it works absolutely fine....

Comment: Try cleaning your project. If everything is set up properly, and there is a jsoup jar in the `libs` folder, Eclipse might not be building your apk correctly.

Comment: thanks man you were right . I reordered the Project libraries and it now works fine..................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` because your jar file is not available at runtime. In order for it to be available at runtime you'll have to put it in your libs folder and check the checkboxes on your jar file in your java build path like so:

[image]